# getting recarray into postgres using psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, numpy, psycopg2, recarray

Just would like to get a quick idea on the best, meaning least coding, way to get lots of data in recarray into postgres using psycopg2. I have seen some stuff using cast but really I thought it would be strait forward and I could find something good on the web.

Example have census data with 200 variables read in recarray with different data types for many columns. I want to just sweep through using column names and data types and input into postgres.

Also if there is anything better than psycopy2 I am open to suggestions.

This is what I found although it goes into sqlight and the wrong way.

```
elif driver=='sqlite3':
                    tups=cur.fetchall()
                    if len(tups)>0:
                            _cast = {types.BooleanType: numpy.bool,
                                    types.IntType: numpy.int32,
                                    types.LongType: numpy.int64,
                                    types.FloatType: numpy.float64,
                                    types.StringType: numpy.str,
                                    types.UnicodeType: numpy.str}
                            try:
                                    typelist=[_cast[type(tmp)] for tmp in tups[0]]
                            except KeyError:
                                    raise Exception("Unknown datatype")
                            res = numpy.core.records.array(tups)
                    else:
                            return None
            res=[res[tmp] for tmp in res.dtype.names]
    except BaseException:
```

Answer (score 2):

Psycopg can be extended using a new adapter (when you want to pass a Python object to Postgres) or a new typecaster (when you want to read from Postgres and get Python objects).

It looks like you have to [register](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/advanced.html#adapting-new-python-types-to-sql-syntax) some of the existing adapters for the numpy types, for instance:

```
>>> psycopg2.extensions.register_adapter(numpy.int32, psycopg2._psycopg.AsIs)
>>> psycopg2.extensions.adapt(numpy.int32(42)).getquoted()
'42'

>>> psycopg2.extensions.register_adapter(numpy.str, psycopg2._psycopg.QuotedString)
>>> psycopg2.extensions.adapt(numpy.str("Hi 'quote'")).getquoted()
"'Hi ''quote'''"
```

With these registrations you can use numpy types directly as query parameters.

You may get more details and help on the [Mailing List](http://mail.postgresql.org/mj/mj_wwwusr/domain=postgresql.org?func=lists-long-full&extra=psycopg).